# Qt6 QML: как сделать маску прозрачности?

Tags: qt, qml

Мне нужно у объекта Image в QML сделать скруглённые края.
В прежних версиях QML был модуль QtGraphicalEffects содержащий класс OpacityMask, который позволял задать произвольную фигуру и по ней обрезать объект. В частности в моём случае на вход OpacityMask подавался прямоугольник со скруглёнными краями:

```
layer.enabled: true
layer.effect: OpacityMask {
    maskSource: Rectangle {
        radius: 10
        width: root.width
        height: root.height
        visible: false
    }
}
```

В Qt6 такого модуля нет. Там вроде как предлагается вместо QtGraphicalEffects использовать ShaderEffect. Я посмотрел документацию на него - выглядит страшновато и непонятно.

Есть ли попроще способ скруглить края? Ну или может быть где-то есть готовое решение с использованием ShaderEffect позволяющее применить маску прозрачности по заданной фигуре?

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы делать маску по старинке, импортируйте следующий модуль

```
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects
```